# how to populate Textbox on Calendar selection changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
   <div style="text-align:center">

        <asp:Calendar ID="myCal" runat="server" Height="600px" width="900px" 
            BorderColor="#F2F3F4" BorderWidth="3px" DayStyle-BorderWidth="1px" 
                    TodayDayStyle-BackColor="#82CAFF" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" 
            SelectionMode="Day" DayHeaderStyle-Height="30px" 
                    TitleStyle-BackColor="#CBE3F0" TitleStyle-ForeColor="#153E7E" 
            OtherMonthDayStyle-ForeColor="#B4CFEC" NextPrevStyle-ForeColor="#2554C7" 
            CssClass="mGrid" onselectionchanged="myCal_SelectionChanged">
            <DayHeaderStyle Height="30px" /><TitleStyle Height="50px" />
            <DayStyle BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CBE3F0" />
        </asp:Calendar>

    </div>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelect" runat="server" width="200px" Height="200px"  >

       <table border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:white">
            <tr>
                <td align="right"></td>
                <td>
                    <h2>New Appointment</h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Start Date:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">End Date:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEnd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Name:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonOK" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonOK_Click" Text="OK" />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="ButtonCancel_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="myCal" PopupControlID="pnlSelect"
         OkControlID="ButtonOK" CancelControlID="ButtonCancel" Drag="True">

    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I want to populate the current date in the Popup however the `myCal_SelectionChanged` event is not firing

How do i achieve this

**Please help**

Answer (score 0):

your code is worked fine for me .create a new testpage and try again using same code 
if it works then.. may be you have a problem in your page designer.cs

Comment: Are you getting the date in the textbox of the popup?

Comment: I think what happen at your model pop up extender as per my experience .Model pop-up copy your `myCal` Generated HTML to its div and when you click on show it display and when you change your calender selection event not happen because original HTML is removed .

Comment: your above code not working coz if you do postback then page is reload and your pop-up hide again so, try using another method like jquery pop.or window pop up..